# Typo in Wikipedia article on Gaussian integral?

Tags: determinant, gaussian-integral

[Relevant section of article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#n-dimensional_and_functional_generalization)

As of time of writing, the article says:

> Suppose $A$ is a symmetric positive-definite (hence invertible) $n \times n$ precision matrix, which is the matrix inverse of the covariance matrix. Then,
>
> $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp{\left(-\frac 1 2 \sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{n}A_{ij} x_i x_j \right)} \, d^nx =\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp{\left(-\frac 1 2 x^{T} A x \right)} \, d^nx=\sqrt{\frac{(2\pi)^n}{\det A}} =\sqrt{\frac{1}{\det (A / 2\pi)}} =\sqrt{\det (2 \pi A^{-1})}$
>
> where the integral is understood to be over $R^n$.

I am wondering if the three determinants on the far right should be $|\mathrm{det}A|,|\mathrm{det}(A/2\pi)|, |\mathrm{det}(2\pi A^{-1})|$ - in other words, have an absolute value sign. Reason for this is if the determinant is negative, then the three expressions are all imaginary, but I don't see why the Gaussian integral would *a priori* be imaginary or even how it can be imaginary in the first place, given that $A$ is positive-definite.

Comment: If $A$ is positive-definite, then $\det A>0$.

Comment: Also, if $A$ is not positive-definite, then the integral does not converge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is positive-definite, so $\det A > 0$, $\det(A/2\pi) > 0$, and $\det(2\pi A^{-1}) > 0$.

See [Does a positive definite matrix have positive determinant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/892729/does-a-positive-definite-matrix-have-positive-determinant) for more on this.